# Give an example of a non-abelian group $G$ such that $H = \{a \in G \mid\operatorname{ord}(a) < \infty\}$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

> Give and example of a non-abelian group $G$ such that $H = \{a \in G\mid\operatorname{ord}(a) < \infty\}$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Firstly, I thought about $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, as multiplication of matrices is not commutative, I tried to shrink $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ by introducing some special cases, as for example $G = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & a \\
0 & b 
\end{pmatrix} : b \neq 0\right\}$ and found $H = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & a \\
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix} : a\in \mathbb R \right\}$, but in fact H is subgroup of G. Any suggestions?

Take $G = GL_2(\mathbb R)$, and assume $H =  \{a \in G \mid\operatorname{ord}(a) < \infty\}$ is subgroup of $G$. Consider $\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1/2 \\
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \in H$,  as $ \ \ \ \ \  \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} = I$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1/2 \\
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1/2 \\
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = I$

$W = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1/2 \\
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2
\end{pmatrix} \not \in H$ as $ord(W) = \infty$, therefore by Subgroup Criterion contradiction $\implies$ $H$ is not subgroup of $G$.

Comment: have you learned about free groups or free products?

Comment: sorry, but I haven't

Comment: The most familiar example is the infinite dihedral group (which is in fact a free product of two groups of order 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe think about the dihedral analogue but on a circle instead of a polygon.  Pick a reflection about a line of symmetry through 1 radian and one about 2 radians (you just need them to not be a multiple of $\pi$).  Then each is its own inverse so they would be in this torsion set since their order is $2$.  But when you multiply them you should get just a rotation of an integer multiple of radians.  This should have infinite order because it will never get to $2\pi n$ since if it did, it would mean $\pi$ is rational.